# SP 2013 Rest Filter the Created field to return only items from current year

Tags: javascript, rest, jquery

I am trying to filter the list items by the year and then count those list items. This is as far as I got, but it produces an error. I guess there's an issue with the filter syntax. Can anyone help?

```
var year = new Date().getFullYear().toString();

function(){
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'BF20B386-CF99-4353-B889-6BBB99612420')/items?$select=Created&$filter=(Created startsWith 'year')",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){

        console.log(data.d.results); 

        },
    error:  function(){
      alert("Failed to query SharePoint list data. Please refresh (F5).");
}});
```

}
}

EDIT:

As it was pointed out, the Created field is an integer, and startsWith will not work. I like the solution provided using greater than 2017-01-01... but that is not dynamic. I'd have to change it next year. So instead, i found another column that had the date in a string and used the substringof function to accomplish the task:

```
$.ajax({
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'BF20B386-CF99-4353-B889-6BBB99612420')/items?$filter=substringof('" + year + "',Title)",
    type: "GET",
    headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
    success: function(data){
        var newpermnum = data.d.results.length + 1;
        console.log(data.d.results.length + 1); 

        },
    error:  function(){
      alert("Failed to query SharePoint list data. Please refresh (F5).");
}});
```

Q: this is my first question! Should I mark an answer as correct even thought i found a different work around?

Comment: Have you tried e.g. `filter=Created eq '2016'`

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use a greater than or less than comparison when working with a datetime field rather than starts with (used for string comparison).

```
$.ajax({

url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'BF20B386-CF99-4353-B889-6BBB99612420')/items?$select=Created&$filter=Start_x0020_Date ge datetime'2017-01-01T00:00:01Z')",

....
```

Comment: I just found a workaround for my issue. I used a different column that contained the date in string and used the substringof function to filter out the list items using my year variable: 

$.ajax({
     url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/Web/Lists(guid'BF20B386-CF99-4353-B889-6BBB99612420')/items?$filter=substringof('" + year + "',Title)",
     type: "GET",
     headers: { "ACCEPT": "application/json;odata=verbose" },
     success: function(data){
   var newpermnum = data.d.results.length + 1;
      console.log(data.d.results.length + 1); 

    },

Comment: also i'm really sorry, this is my first question and i'm not familiar with the correct protocol here.

Comment: No worries. Bear in mind that you may be dealing with a unindexed column and it may be a bit slower if the list you're working with grows. Whatever works. :)